# Unable to rotate image in PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to change the angle of the image by using matrix.Its a needle image which points the value in a chart.
If i am giving "at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));" , then its looking like it went inside the page, but i need it in the page.

Here is the code i m trying

```
//Retrieving the pages of the document 
      PDPage page = document.getPage(0);

    //Creating PDImageXObject object
      PDImageXObject needle = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("SpeedometerNeedle-300dpi-ActualSize.png"
              ,document);

     PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
     //Drawing the image in the PDF document
    // draw 90° rotated, placed on the right of the first image
      Matrix at = new Matrix(needle.getHeight() / 4, 0, 0, needle.getWidth() / 4,120, 565);
      at.rotate(Math.toRadians(45));
    // contentStream.drawImage(needle, 100, 565, needle.getWidth() / 4, needle.getHeight() / 4);
     contentStream.drawImage(needle,at);
     contentStream.close();
```

I am using org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.1 version ,So if i am trying to use

```
 AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform(ximage.getHeight() / 2, 0, 0, ximage.getWidth() / 2, x + ximage1.getWidth(), y);
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, at);
```

Then drawXObject method is shown as deprecated.
So suggest me how to use it.

Comment: I assume your basic issue is that the image is not rotated around its own center but instead around the origin of the coordinate system. You, therefore, have to combine the pure rotation with a translation to counteract this effect.

Comment: Did you read the deprecation notice? It says to use drawImage. You can convert an AffineTransform to a Matrix by using the constructor.